# SwiftUI: how do I conditionally present ActionSheet only on iOS?

Tags: swiftui

I’ve started to like an approach where I write crossplatform UI code with SwiftUI. The app would still be started with a native window/container, but have a fully crossplatform SwiftUI-driven UI. For many standard things things like list, navigationview etc, it is very useful and works fine.

The problem arises with some platform-specific view extensions. I would like to write this code in a platform-agnostic fashion, but not sure how to do it for some specific cases.

First, here’s a working example of a crossplatform conditional view modifier.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, demo!").padding()
            .modifier(iosBackground())
    }
}

struct iosBackground: ViewModifier {
    #if os(OSX)
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
    #else
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(Color.blue)
    }
    #endif
}
```

What the `iosBackground` modifier is doing, is applying a view modification only on the iOS platform (well, to be specific, on any non-OSX platform, but let’s just work with OSX and iOS in this example). The OSX version of the view is passed through, while the iOS version returns a modified view. This color example is of course dumb and useless, but for layout-related things like padding, it is a highly practical approach.

**My question: how do I apply the same approach to modifiers like actionSheet?** Here’s what I would like to do:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State var showActionSheet = true
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, demo!").padding()
            .modifier(iosBackground())
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(
                    title: Text("Actions"),
                    message: Text("Available actions"),
                    buttons: [
                        .cancel { },
                        .default(Text("Action")),
                        .destructive(Text("Delete"))
                    ]
                )
            }

    }
}
```

If you try to compile this code, it works fine on iOS. On OSX, it has a compilation error because the `actionSheet` API is not available on OSX. Which, indeed, is the case. I would like to make it so that the `actionSheet` call would simply be a no-op on OSX, but I can’t figure out how to structure and conditionally compile my code to make it happen.

The question, once again: how can I structure this code so that on iOS, actionSheet would be presented, while on OSX, it would be a no-op?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You would have found the way if you took a look at the `.actionSheet`'s function signature. It returns an opaque type of `some View` that is the return type of almost all the SwiftUI views. So, look at the documentation too:

```
/// Presents an action sheet.
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - isPresented: A `Binding` to whether the action sheet should be
///     shown.
///     - content: A closure returning the `ActionSheet` to present.
@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@available(OSX, unavailable)
public func actionSheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> ActionSheet) -> some View
```

That being said, you could use this as like as you have used the `.background` function in conjunction with the content. So, here is the solution:

```
struct Sheet: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var presented: Bool

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        #if os(OSX)
        return content
        #else
        return content
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $presented) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Action Title"),
                            message: Text("Action Message"),
                            buttons: [.cancel(), .default(Text("Ok"))]
                )
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

I just moved the `#if - #endif` inside the function body and that requires the `return` keyword explicitly. And you would use this as any modifier:

```
.modifier(Sheet(presented: $showActionSheet))
```

Comment: Thank you. Works as expected.